# z-index not hide element

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with z-index, I want to positionate .hidtable behind section, but it is in front, can somebody help me to undestand where is the problem? maybe I miss something?

```css
.content{
  position:relative,
  z-index:0
}

.hidtable{  
    z-index: -1; 
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<section class="content">
   <table class="hidtable">
      <thead >
       <th>th1</th>
          <th>th2</th>
      </thead>
        <tr>tr1</tr>
        <tr>tr2</tr>
   </table>
</section>
```

Comment: By definition: "The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.", I think you're looking for `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`

Comment: do you want to hide div  only

Comment: z-index doesn't hide elements you have to use `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`

Comment: Why don't you consider using the display property instead of the z-index property ?

Comment: sorry, bad word, I want the table behind the section

Comment: `relative,
  z-index:0` is not a valid value for `position`. And if you position the only child absolute, the section will have no height any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hidtable is part of the section so I don't think you can position it behind like that. You can only position things behind completely seperate elements. So if you take the table out of section and add a width and a height to section you should get what you're trying to achieve.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
        .content {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background: #ffffff;
        }

        .hidtable {
            z-index: -1;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background: #ffffff;
            display: block;
        }

        </style>
        <section class="content">
        </section>
        <table class="hidtable">
                <thead>
                    <th>th1</th>
                    <th>th2</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <td>tr1</td>
                    <td>tr2</td>
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: using the visibility property will cause the place taken by the table to stay occupied , He should use the display property , .hidtable { display : none: }

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `display` property.

```
.hidtable{  
    display: none;
}
```

Further info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Additionally, you have a syntax error in your css code, you should replace the comma after the first `position: relative` with a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

If you are not familiar with the z-axis, imagine the page has several layers one above the other. Each layer is numbered. A layer with a greater number is rendered above layers with smaller numbers.

It doesn't mean it will hide the layers with lower index

use `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`

read [how does z-index work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index)

Answer (score 0):

If one element is behind the other and you still can see it, the reason is that the front element doesn't have a background and therefore is partly transparent. Add a background color to change that.

Here is the situation in a snippet based on your code. However, I changed quite a bit, since your code is invalid HTML (`tr`s, but not `td`s and other stuff). Also, since your `.content` doesn't have any content other than the absolute element, you have to give it size parameters to cover the table:

```css
.content {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.hidtable {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<section class="content">
  <table class="hidtable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>th1</th>
        <th>th2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>tr1</td>
        <td>tr2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you only use z-index to layer elements. To hide an element I would use

```
<style>
.hidtable{
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

This will not show the element. To get it to show again you should use:

```
<style>
.hidtable{
    display: inline;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

reference:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp